# Audit Log in the database using Entity Farmework mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is my code which I am using to when update the record from my code.

```
 if (dbEntry.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            foreach (string propertyName in dbEntry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
            {
                // For updates, we only want to capture the columns that actually changed
                if (!object.Equals(dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName), dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName)))
                {
                    result.Add(new AuditLog1()
                    {
                        AuditLogID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        UserID = userId,
                        EventDateUTC = changeTime,
                        EventType = "M",    // Modified
                        TableName = tableName,
                        RecordID = dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(keyName).ToString(),
                        ColumnName = propertyName,
                        OriginalValue = dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName) == null ? null : dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString(),
                        NewValue = dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName) == null ? null : dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString()
                    }
                        );
                }
            }
        }
```

But this code does not put log in my AuditLog Table in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding to the context. but you need to call the method that actually save them to the database. (SaveChanges method shown later).

..............

In general: you need to add your items to your `DbSet<MyThing> MyThings` on your myDbContext.

example:

```
myDbConext.AuditLogs.Add(theNewAuditLog);
```

ADD them all.........

AND then call one of the following:

```
myDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

or

```
myDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(token); /* token is a CancellationToken */
```

link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechangesasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

here is dotnet core tutorial:

https://entityframeworkcore.com/saving-data-savechangesasync

here is entity framework (dot net framework) tutorial:

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/async-query-and-save.aspx

APPEND:

You asked a different question about Edit not working.

this is my typical edit code.

```
public async Task<MyThing> UpdateAsync(MyThing inputItem, CancellationToken token)
{
    int saveChangesAsyncValue = 0;
    MyThing foundEntity = await this.entityDbContext.MyThings.FirstOrDefaultAsync(item => item.MySurrogateKey == inputItem.MySurrogateKey, token);
    if (null != foundEntity)
    {
        foundEntity.MyStringPropertyOne = inputItem.MyStringPropertyOne;
        foundEntity.MyStringPropertyTwo = inputItem.MyStringPropertyTwo;


        this.entityDbContext.Entry(foundEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;

        saveChangesAsyncValue = await this.entityDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(token);

        /* an exception here would suggest another process changed the "context" but did not commit the changes (usually by SaveChanges() or SaveChangesAsync() */
        if (1 != saveChangesAsyncValue)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format(ErrorMsgExpectedSaveChangesAsyncRowCount, saveChangesAsyncValue), (Exception)null);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ArgumentOutOfRangeException argEx = new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format(" SAD FACE {0} ", entity.MyThingKey), (Exception)null);
        this.logger.LogError(argEx);
        throw argEx;
    }

    return foundEntity;
}
```

Comment: The if condition is not working it's always picking the original and current values same. How I can do this ??

Comment: I think you should try just setting all properties without the if check.  I believe EF will already internally figure out what has changed and only generate SQL for truly different columns.not to be mean, but I think your property code reflection checking is "too clever" code.  If you check this line it will show you how to wire to a logger to see generated SQL : https://github.com/granadacoder/oracle-ef-issues-demo/blob/master/src/DataLayer.EntityFramework/Contexts/EfPlaygroundDbContext.cs#L66

Comment: Thank you for helping me :) but the problem is when I edit my form then it only takes the current values .... the codition I am using will diffenciate  that which column values has changed .. please give me suggestions for add and delete it is working fine it is only gives me issue for modified

Answer (score 0):

```js
dbEntry.AuditLogs.add(new AuditLog()
                    {
                        AuditLogID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        UserID = userId,
                        EventDateUTC = changeTime,
                        EventType = "M",    // Modified
                        TableName = tableName,
                        RecordID = dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(keyName).ToString(),
                        ColumnName = propertyName,
                        OriginalValue = dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName) == null ? null : dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString(),
                        NewValue = dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName) == null ? null : dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString()
                    });
dbEntry.Savechanges();
```